# onChangeText returning object Object instead of the value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change the data fetched from an API by changing the endpoint of the URL in react native. I have tried several ways but I an getting [object Object] at the end instead of the query.
It can be seen in the console.log(baseurl) statement in line 52.
Here is my code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, StyleSheet,  Linking, ScrollView, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

function Update() {
  const [data, setData]= useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading]= useState(true);
  const [query, setQuery]= useState("");

  const baseurl="https://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs/in/search/2?app_id=6fb4d871&app_key=51579f6594c9d91943719f071dfcff72&results_per_page=15&what_and="+{query};

function getData() {
    return (
      fetch(baseurl)
      .then((response)=> response.json())
    )
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
    .then((responseJson)=>{
     setData(responseJson.results),
     setLoading(false)
    }) 
    .catch(err=> console.log(err))
  },[]);

    if(loading) {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, padding:10}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </ScrollView>
      ) 
      
     }else{
       let updates= data.map((val, key)=>{
         return <View key={key} >
           
           <Text style={styles.head}>{val.company.display_name}</Text>
           <Text style={styles.type}>{val.contract_type}</Text>
           <Text style={styles.location}>{val.location.area}</Text>
           <Text style={styles.desc}>{val.description}</Text>
           <Text style={styles.link}
                onPress={() => Linking.openURL(val.redirect_url)}>
            Read more..
          </Text>
         </View>
       })

      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput value={query} onChangeText={(query)=>{setQuery(query), console.log(query), console.log(baseurl)}}  
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}/>
          <Text style={styles.top}>Here's your weekly Job update! </Text>
           {updates} 
        </ScrollView>
        
       )
     }
  }

export default Update;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything in the react-native-gesture-handler docs regarding a TextInput, my first thought would be to see the signature of onChangeText

Comment: Or maybe `TextInput` should be placed as part of the "react-native" import components, because react-native does offer [`TextInput`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput).

Answer (score 0):

`TextInput` is part of `react-native` and you can import it from `react-native` module

Add `TextInput` in your `react-native` module

```
import {View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, StyleSheet,  Linking, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TextInput} from 'react-native';
```

Remove below line

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Comment: I did change the import but the problem still persists. :/

Comment: thats not possible, please create demo of your problem in snake expo

Comment: Sure. Here's the link: https://snack.expo.io/BJG7lQBEG